# Illegal url for new iframe when pushed from a windows machine

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using the google sign in button for my firebase project which works as intended when it is pushed from a mac.

However when pushed from a windows machine I received the following error when I hit the google sign in button:

```
2.b95cb065.chunk.js:2 Uncaught Error: Illegal url for new iframe - https://***.firebaseapp.com%0D/__/auth/iframe?apiKey=***%0D&appName=%5BDEFAULT%5D-firebaseui-temp&v=8.2.5&fw=FirebaseUI-web&usegapi=1&jsh=m%3B%2F_%2Fscs%2Fabc-static%2F_%2Fjs%2Fk%3Dgapi.lb.en.ydLROSGdlBE.O%2Fd%3D1%2Frs%3DAHpOoo_OUY4V-VcsLuRVnUuYVO758FydkA%2Fm%3D__features__#id=I0_1671205169815&_gfid=I0_1671205169815&parent=https%3A%2F%2F***.firebaseapp.com&pfname=&rpctoken=40576440
    at _.Vk (cb=gapi.loaded_0?le=scs:148:96)
    at yl (cb=gapi.loaded_0?le=scs:158:18)
    at _.zl (cb=gapi.loaded_0?le=scs:159:26)
    at _.Gl (cb=gapi.loaded_0?le=scs:165:147)
    at _.Wm.openChild (cb=gapi.loaded_0?le=scs:268:378)
    at _.Wm.open (cb=gapi.loaded_0?le=scs:273:12)
    at 2.b95cb065.chunk.js:2:921890
    at new Et (2.b95cb065.chunk.js:2:849923)
    at 2.b95cb065.chunk.js:2:921836
    at Dt.i.a.i.g (2.b95cb065.chunk.js:2:851228)
```

This is how I initalize firebase:

```
const firebaseConfig = {

  apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_APIKEY,
  authDomain: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_AUTHDOMAIN,
  projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECTID,
  storageBucket: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_STORAGEBUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_MESSAGINGSENDERID,
  appId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_APPID,
};

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "development") {
  console.log(firebaseConfig);
}

export const app = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);


(async () => {
  await firebase.auth().setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.SESSION);
})();

export default firebase;
```

And this is how the environmental variables are defined:

```
REACT_APP_FIREBASE_APIKEY=***
REACT_APP_FIREBASE_AUTHDOMAIN=***.firebaseapp.com
REACT_APP_FIREBASE_DATABASEURL=
REACT_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECTID=***
REACT_APP_FIREBASE_STORAGEBUCKET=***.appspot.com
REACT_APP_FIREBASE_MESSAGINGSENDERID=***
REACT_APP_FIREBASE_APPID=***
REACT_APP_ENV=development
```

The url is not in quotes and there are no commas in it and it also does not start with `https://`

Comment: The error shows `%0D` (url-encoded carriage return) appended to the env var items. I suspect this is due to an issue with a file format or copy/paste.

Comment: but how can I solve it? the same code base works fine on mac but not on windows

Comment: It depends on how you're setting your env vars. At a guess, use an editor that gives you control over line endings. (Macs typically use `\r` while windows typically uses `\n\r`. Some editors give you control over this.)

Comment: ok I see, on mac I am using Jetbrains Webstorm while on Windows I am using VS Code.

Comment: so I added the settings to VSCode however both .env files on both systems have LF so that should be fine right? The code is compiles via react-scripts but since both files are LF I don't see why the line endings should change...